# Simple HTML/Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML page that is supposed to pick a random image from a folder  I have local. If I change src to "images/gif10.gif" for example, the page works fine. I am very new to Javascript and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>New Tab</title>
  <div id="bg">
      <img id="gb" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <style>
    #bg {
      position: fixed; 
      top: -50%; 
      left: -50%; 
      width: 200%; 
      height: 200%;
    }
    #bg img {
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      margin: auto; 
      min-width: 50%;
      min-height: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        var imgName = "gif" + randomNumber + ".gif";
        document.getElementById("gb").src= "images/" + imgName ;
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have elements like div and img outside the body

Comment: Your code, copied and pasted exactly as it is, works just fine.  Though as stated in a previous comment, it *is* structurally invalid HTML.  But the JavaScript part works.

Comment: The div from head must be put in body tag.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The real problem was that I was running inline JS inside a chrome extension, which it didn't really like. I made a separate JS file and allowed it through the manifest and all is good! Also, I fixed my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var imgName = "technics-q-c-640-480-" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("gb").src= "http://lorempixel.com/output/" + imgName ;
}
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>New Tab</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="bg">
      <img id="gb" src="" alt="">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```